# Finding the derivative of y

Tags: derivatives

> If $$y= \arccos \frac{2x-3\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{13}}$$ ,find $\frac{dy}{dx}.$

Please help me solve this.

 Thank you

Comment: I think you should learn from your previous question like this. Please see @Brian's answer again.

Comment: I agree with @Babak: this is *very* much like [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475566/differentiation-with-respect-to-x).

Comment: Id like to get to the answer Without Directly applying chain rule

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Putting $x=\cos B, 2=r\cos A,3=r\sin A$ where $r>0$

$(r\cos A)^2+(r\sin A)^2=2^2+3^2=13$

$\implies r=\sqrt{13}$ as $r>0$

and $\cos A=\frac2{\sqrt{13}},\sin A=\frac3{\sqrt{13}}$

$$\implies \frac{2x-3\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{13}}=\cos B\cos A-\sin A\sin B=\cos(A+B)=\cos \left(\arccos\frac2{\sqrt{13}}+\arccos x\right)$$

$$\implies  \arccos\left(\frac{2x-3\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{13}}\right)=\arccos\frac2{\sqrt{13}}+\arccos x$$

Comment: +1 However, personally, I preferred you leave some parts for the OP unsolved or hidden. :-)

Comment: @BabakS., the last line ? :)

Comment: It can be, lab. :-)